# Sliced and displaced image on monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, dvi

We have a system where a monitor is hooked up to a PC through a KVM switch. The KVM switch switches the video output from the PC to different monitors but always one at a time and the same model monitors.

Sometimes when the image is switched to another monitor, a part of the image is sliced and placed on another part of the monitor. Nothing is lost and the resolution itself doesn't change but a section is displaced. Whenever the KVM switch disconnects the image from the monitor and reconnects it the issue will be gone.

The problem always occurs on the right side of the monitor but the size of the sliced part differs.

To avoid displacement initiated by windows we read the EDID information from an exported file instead of reading it from the monitor (can be set up in the NVidia configuration -> System topology).

PC specs:

```
Intel i7-4790S CPU
Asus CS-B motherboard
Kingston HyperX Fury Black 4GB RAM
NVidia Quadro K620 Graphics card (only DVI connection is used)
```

Monitor:

```
IIyama
PROLITE XB3070WQS-B1
2560x1600 resolution hooked up with Dual-Link DVI
```

Unfortunately I don't have any information about the KVM switch because another party supplied and configured it.

Is there anything I can check that can explain this behaviour and find the faulty component/setting in this setup?

An example of the situation when the image is displaced:
[image]